# Soundcloud Google Signin not working for getting song list

Tags: ios, soundcloud

I want to show songs list in my iphone application.
When i use signin using google account,i can't get "accesstoken" or song list.And the webpage remain blank.
I can get it by using facebook and soundcloud account.
Does anyone has idea how to achive this goal?